Unable to activate the controllers
I am getting this errosr as I try to launch the launch_control file mentioned in the tutorial:
https://docs.ros.org/en/ros2_packages/humble/api/ur_robot_driver/usage.html#usage-with-official-ur-simulator 1
Terminal Error:
    [ur_ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1730290493.676137945] [controller_manager]: Could not switch controllers since prepare command mode switch was rejected.
[spawner-7] [ERROR] [1730290493.676712684] [spawner_scaled_joint_trajectory_controller]: Failed to activate controller
[ERROR] [spawner-7]: process has died [pid 60865, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner scaled_joint_trajectory_controller -c /controller_manager --controller-manager-timeout 10 --ros-args'].
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1730290493.837923710] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'forward_position_controller'
[spawner-9] [INFO] [1730290493.847248210] [spawner_forward_position_controller]: Loaded forward_position_controller
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1730290493.847691292] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1730290493.856574694] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'forward_position_controller'
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1730290493.857981456] [forward_position_controller]: configure successful
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1730290493.858176362] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1730290493.859351579] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1730290493.859418204] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1730290493.864296986] [joint_state_broadcaster]: None of requested interfaces exist. Controller will not run.
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [WARN] [1730290493.864340608] [joint_state_broadcaster]: Error occurred while doing error handling.
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1730290493.864395731] [controller_manager]: After activation, controller 'joint_state_broadcaster' is in state 'unconfigured' (1), expected 'active' (3).
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1730290493.867560715] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1730290493.869792676] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'io_and_status_controller'
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1730290493.879006619] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded io_and_status_controller
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1730290493.879816439] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'io_and_status_controller'
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1730290493.881828768] [resource_manager]: Not acceptable command interfaces combination: 
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] Start interfaces: 
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_0
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_1
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_2
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_3
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_4
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_5
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_6
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_7
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_8
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_9
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_10
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_11
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_12
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_13
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_14
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_15
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_16
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_17
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_analog_output_cmd_0
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/standard_analog_output_cmd_1
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/tool_voltage_cmd
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   gpio/io_async_success
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   speed_scaling/target_speed_fraction_cmd
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   speed_scaling/target_speed_fraction_async_success
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   resend_robot_program/resend_robot_program_cmd
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   resend_robot_program/resend_robot_program_async_success
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   payload/mass
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   payload/cog.x
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   payload/cog.y
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   payload/cog.z
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   payload/payload_async_success
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   zero_ftsensor/zero_ftsensor_cmd
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   zero_ftsensor/zero_ftsensor_async_success
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   hand_back_control/hand_back_control_cmd
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]   hand_back_control/hand_back_control_async_success
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] ]
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] Stop interfaces: 
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] ]
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] Not available: 
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_0
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_1
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_2
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_3
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_4
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_5
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_6
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_7
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_8
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_9
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_10
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_11
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_12
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_13
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_14
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_15
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_16
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_digital_output_cmd_17
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_analog_output_cmd_0
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/standard_analog_output_cmd_1
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/tool_voltage_cmd
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  gpio/io_async_success
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  speed_scaling/target_speed_fraction_cmd
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  speed_scaling/target_speed_fraction_async_success
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  resend_robot_program/resend_robot_program_cmd
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  resend_robot_program/resend_robot_program_async_success
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  payload/mass
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  payload/cog.x
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  payload/cog.y
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  payload/cog.z
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  payload/payload_async_success
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  zero_ftsensor/zero_ftsensor_cmd
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  zero_ftsensor/zero_ftsensor_async_success
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  hand_back_control/hand_back_control_cmd
[ur_ros2_control_node-1]  hand_back_control/hand_back_control_async_success
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] ]
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] 
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1730290493.881870236] [controller_manager]: Could not switch controllers since prepare command mode switch was rejected.
[spawner-8] [ERROR] [1730290493.882510368] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Failed to activate controller
[INFO] [spawner-9]: process has finished cleanly [pid 60869]
[ERROR] [spawner-8]: process has died [pid 60867, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner --controller-manager /controller_manager --controller-manager-timeout 10 joint_state_broadcaster io_and_status_controller speed_scaling_state_broadcaster force_torque_sensor_broadcaster --ros-args'].

I checked with the command:
ros2 control list_controllers
forward_position_controller position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController inactive
scaled_joint_trajectory_controller ur_controllers/ScaledJointTrajectoryController inactive
io_and_status_controller ur_controllers/GPIOController inactive
joint_state_broadcaster joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster unconfigured

and tried to activate the controllers using:
ros2 control set_controller_state scaled_joint_trajectory_controller active
but I get the error:
Error activating controller, check controller_manager logs

How do I solve this problem? I want to control the UR20 from my PC using ROS
